# spacy - pattern matching

Tags: python, spacy

I want to try to see how I can use spaCy pattern matching to find product categories that have are being referenced in text. I am obviously not constructing this correctly.

I want to identify CAT-POS-2299 as a product. I have tried a few different variations. How would you do this where you could even look for a more general pattern CAT-???-???

Maybe I should be using something else?

Code:

````
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

matcher.add("Product", None,
            [{"LOWER": "CAT"},{"LOWER":"-"},{"LOWER":"POS"},{"LOWER":"-"},{"IS_DIGIT":True}]
           )

doc = nlp(" We have a new product CAT-POS-2299 that will be available to users soon.")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check how your input string is tokenized, you will see that `POS-2299` comes out a single token:

```py
print([t.text for t in doc])
[' ', 'We', 'have', 'a', 'new', 'product', 'CAT', '-', 'POS-2299', 'that', 'will', 'be', 'available', 'to', 'users', 'soon', '.']
```

So, if you plan to match `CAT` word in a case insensitive way, then match a `-` token, and then match any ASCII letter only word followed with `-` and any one or more digits, you may use

```py
matcher.add("Product", None, [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "(?i)CAT"}},{"TEXT":"-"},{"TEXT": {"REGEX": r"(?i)[A-Z]+-\d+"}}])
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)

# => 16898055450696666743 Product 6 9 CAT-POS-2299
```

Since you are looking to make the pattern more generic, I think using `REGEX` tokens makes sense.

**NOTE**:

- `(?i)CAT` - matches `CAT` in a case insensitive way
- `(?i)[A-Z]+-\d+` - matches any one or more letters (`[A-Z]`) in a case insensitive way (`(?i)`), then `-` and then one or more digits (`\d+`).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! I did not even think about looking at the tokeniztion